# is there any other way than .toFixed() method, in suitlet to print a 2 decimal placed number as a 3 decimal place?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

is there any way in suitlet to print a 2 decimal placed number as a 3 decimal place? (e.g, the value i have is 1300.12 and i want it to be printed as 1300.120). I have tried .toFixed(3) method but my suitlet is showing error.”

Comment: `1300.12.toFixed(3)` this works fine for me, can you reproduce error ?

Comment: `toFixed()` don't work, if the object is a string. In this case try: `parseFloat(text).toFixed(3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(Number.parseFloat(1300.12).toFixed(3))
```

Answer (score 3):

1300.12.toFixed(3) works for me as well.It should work out for you as well but anyways try implementing this :

```
financial = (x) => {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(4);
}

console.log(financial(123.456));
```

Hope this will work out for you